# sending POJO to save on server using RESTful webservices

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am developing a Restful web service which allow user to set all parameters in POJO and send it to server side web service, then web service will store this data and return generated Id back to client. But my POJO has parent-child relationship that contain set of POJO, So how can I do this using RESTful web service. I also written a code to fetch data from server using web service and its working fine. But for this issue please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? If you have a complex object then you will have to supply it in the body of your request. This could be XML or JSON; try looking at some REST examples of POST and PUT using your frameworks.

Comment: @James I want to pass a complex object as described above and get response of generated Id but I am confused how to code it could you please help me? And sorry about my language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly. I guess some sample code will help. If you are using `RestTemplate` then serializing and deserializing will be done for you automatically. RestTemplate uses `Jackson` to parse JSON so you don't need to worry about parent/child relationship in your POJO.

So here is an example. There are 1000's of examples out there on internet. Thats how I learnt.

```
RestTemplate restclient = new RestTemplate();
Product product = restclient.getForObject(url,Product.class);
System.out.println(product.getCoupons().getName());
```

Where as product is (I completely made this up myself),

```
 public  class Product {
      @JsonProperty("id")
      private String id;
      @JsonProperty("coupons")
      private Coupons coupons;

      @JsonProperty("id")
      public String getId() {
        return id;
      }
      @JsonProperty("id")
      public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
      }
      @JsonProperty("coupons")
      public Coupons getCoupons() {
       return coupons;
      }
      @JsonProperty("coupons")
      public void setCoupons(Coupons coupons) {
       this.coupons = coupons;
     }
}
public class Coupons {
     @JsonProperty("name")
     private String name;
     @JsonProperty("name")
     public String getName() {
        return name;
     }
     @JsonProperty("name")
     public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
     }
}
```

Let me know if I misunderstood your question, I can update my answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your replay, your guess is write but can your provide me some code example to pass complex object using POST or PUT method with RestTemplate.

Comment: what have you tried? what do you mean by complex? By complex you mean a parent class that has many children?

Comment: actually my POJO does not containing only String or Integer it contains Set<anotherPOJO>, List, Object and many more do will it work for this type of POJO and also how to code at server side to get this request.

Comment: It doesn't matter, RestTemplate will take care of it..I am afraid, I cannot help you with the server side..

Comment: How would you do it if the content type is xml